# Add text to the middle of a file based on a matching array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to add text to the middle of a file if a word within an array is detected:

```
array:[hi,bye]
```

Please do not use find and replace.
A sentence from file.txt:

> Oh hi there, Oh bye there.
> New Sentence: Oh hi ~~greet there, Oh bye ~~greet there.

```py
with open(file.txt,r) as f:
    line=f.readlines()
with open(file.txt,a) as f:
    if any(place in line for place in array):
        f.writelines("~~greet")
```

Comment: You want **~~greet** to be added to every item in **file.txt** if it is in **array**?

Comment: Yes every occurrence ie if we see the same items 3 times, such as hi hi hi, we should get hi  ~~greet hi ~~greet hi ~~greet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `re` module:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r"\b(hi|bye)(\s*)")
lines = []
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        lines.append(pat.sub(r"\1 ~~greet\2", line))

print("\n".join(lines))
```

Prints:

```
Oh hi ~~greet there, Oh bye ~~greet there.
```